# How to setup travis to skip script on particular nodejs version

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I run travis on multiple version of NodeJS. E.g. 6, 7, 8, 9.

In the build process, I run code coverage and other things.

Is there a way to skip running those script on particular NodeJS?

e.g. code coverage tool only need to be run on one of the build (e.g. the highest version).

That would save some time for me and resources for travis.

For example, I would like to skip `before_install`, `before_script`, `after_script` and `after_success` on NodeJS 6 and 8 in the `.travis.yml` below:

```
node_js:
  - '9'
  - '8'
  - '6'
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - /^greenkeeper.*$/
before_install:
  - npm install -g greenkeeper-lockfile@1

before_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-update

script:
  - npm run verify

after_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-upload

after_success:
  - npm install -g travis-deploy-once@4
  - travis-deploy-once "npm run semantic-release"
  - npm install --no-save coveralls && npm run coveralls
  - npm install --no-save codecov && npm run codecov
```

Comment: You're building the same project with multiple node versions? Isn't the node version set in the `travis.yml` file?

Comment: Yes. To test it across multiple versions of NodeJS. However some scripts don't need to run. I have updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple if statement:

```
before_install: >
  node_version=$(node -v);
  if  [ ${node_version:1:1} = 9 ]; then
      echo "succes!";
      npm install -g greenkeeper-lockfile@1;
    else
      echo "else";
  fi
```

The if statement checks if the second character of `node -v` equals `9`

The same in one line:

```
before_install:
  - node_version=$(node -v); if [ ${node_version:1:1} = 5 ]; then npm install -g greenkeeper-lockfile@1; else echo "else"; fi
```

PS: I can highly recommend to use bash scripts as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Implementing-Complex-Build-Steps) instead of scripting in `.travis.yml`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to call a script and uses its value? e.g. `before_install: if [ ${./script/isNodeVersion.sh 9 ]; then ...`.

Comment: I would like to do it this way so that all knowledge about Travis is kept within travis.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do in your bash script but it is possible to use a script file in an if statement. Don't forget to make your scripts executable via chmod!

(`echo "node -v" > test.sh;
chmod +x test.sh;`)


`if [[ $(./test.sh) = "v6.11.2" ]]; then echo "then"; else echo "else"; fi`

Comment: Thanks. I'll carefully evaluation this idea. In case I need to run across multiple CI, e.g. Travis and AppVoyer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Night Train, this is what I ended up doing:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $1 = 'latest' ]; then
  target_version=$(npm info node version);
else
  target_version=$1;
fi
node_version=$(node -v);
if [ ${node_version:1:1} = ${target_version:0:1} ]; then
  echo "Detected ${node_version}, satisfying ${target_version}. Executing command";
  eval $2;
else
  echo "NodeJS ${node_version} instead of latest (${target_version:0:1}) is detected. Skipping command";
fi
```

And in the `.travis.yml`:

```
after_success:
  - ./scripts/run-on-node-version.sh latest "npm install --no-save coveralls && npm run coveralls"
  - ./scripts/run-on-node-version.sh latest "npm install --no-save codecov && npm run codecov"
```

This way I can keep the actions in one place (`.travis.yml`) and other CI can use `./scripts/run-on-node-version.sh` for other purposes.

https://gist.github.com/unional/f3ba0ba96df85d7ca957b2df1318dfdf

Comment: you could even pass the script a parameter, like 
`test.sh 'latest'`
and us it in the script
`if [ $1 = 'latest' ]; then latest_version=$(npm info node version); else latest_version=9; fi`